# appengine python datastore - hook to model rollback (regular db api, not ndb)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore

I need to hook into the rollback of a specific model kind when transaction fails.
I'm aware this is simpler with the ndb api. however, I have too much legacy code to migrate right now.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why? Are you doing things in transactions that cause side-effects? Are you aware that there's no guarantee the rollback code will even be called - for instance, if the request handler dies?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever read [this article about using hooks](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/hooks)?
I think you can check if call == 'Rollback' for doing something upon rolling back a transaction.